# Check if vector<int> contains duplicate absolute values

Tags: c++11, vector

Attempting to determine if a vector contains a duplicate. This applies to the absolute value of the elements in the vector. I have tested my implementation with a few cases and have gotten inconsistent results.

```
bool has_duplicate(vector<int> v) {
  vector<int>::iterator it;

  for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    if (v[*it] < 0)  
      v[*it *= -1;
    if (count(v.begin(), v.end(), v[*it]) > 1)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

vector<int> v1 {1, -1};       // true
vector<int> v3 {3, 4, 5, -3}; // true
vector<int> v2 {2, -2};       // false
vector<int> v4 {3, 4, -3};    // false
vector<int> v5 {-1, 1};       // false
```

Any insight on the erroneous implementation is appreciated

Comment: Do the elements in your attempted std::vector 'always' have an integer?

Comment: Yes. The only cases I have tested so far are the ones listed.

Comment: `v[*it]` doesn't make any sense. `*it` gives you the element pointed to already.

Comment: @T.C. You're right. Beside that, however, I might see what the OP is having a problem with. I think the function `count` uses `std::unique` in an unintended way?

Comment: @DeanSeo Huh? Why on earth would`std::count` call `std::unique`?

Comment: @T.C. Oh, you're right. I just expected that the OP'd have implemented his own count algorithm. My bad. (because I first thought `std::sort` and `std::unique` would easily pick out intended elements.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iterator is like a pointer, not like an index, so you're definitely misusing them in your code.  It didn't compile for me.  It looks like you're trying to search every element in the vector against every other element, which is inefficient, with a time complexity closer to O(N^2).  Since your function only wants to see whether a duplicate exists, you can stop as soon as you find one.  By using a set to keep track of what you've found so far, you have a time complexity closer to O(N*log(N)).

```
bool has_duplicate(vector<int> v)
{
  set<int> s;
  for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
    int ai = abs(*i);
    if (s.count(ai)) return true;
    s.insert(ai);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool hasDuplicate(std::vector<int> v)
{
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), ::abs);
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    return std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end()) != v.end();
}
```

Comment: You're misusing `unique`. RTM. How about `adjacent_find` ?

Comment: The OP wants to consider absolute value in the equality test, so the sort() and unique() functions here should take predicates that test this way.